# セグエを使わない画面遷移時の次画面が黒くなる

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

セグエを使わない画面遷移についてなのですが、次画面に遷移した時にビルド画面が黒くなります。
Storyboardを見てみると背景は白なのですが、ビルドすると何故か黒です。
また設置したUI部品も表示されません。

そこで次画面におけるViewControllerで背景色のコードを打ち込むと、反映されます。
(あまりコーディングは得意ではないので、なるべくStoryboardを使用して作業していきたいのですが……)

セグエを使わない画面遷移の場合、次画面の部品設置や背景などのカスタマイズなど、全てViewControllerでコーディングしなければならないのでしょうか？

それか、次画面においてStoryboardを反映させるための設定などあるのでしょうか？

お詳しい方がいましたら、ご回答宜しくお願い致します。

【補足】
以下が現在の遷移元のViewControllerになります。
コメントでご指摘してくださったことを試してみましたが、どうやら部品配置やサイズの見直し、Autolayoutをオフにしてみましたが画面は真っ黒のままです。
一応遷移先の画面は分かりやすく青に設定したのですが、それすら反映されず……という状況です。

```js
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        //ボタン接続の上、セグエを使わずにコーディングだけで画面遷移

        // 遷移するViewを定義する.
        let mySecondViewController: UIViewController = SecondViewController()

        // アニメーションを設定する.
        mySecondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.PartialCurl

        // Viewの移動する.
        self.presentViewController(mySecondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

【再補足】

回答でご指摘されたように、以下のコードを打ちましたが、
(Storyboardの名前は"Main")

```js
let mySecondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController
```

これでは遷移先であるSecondViewController.swiftとstoryboard内で「next」と名付けたViewControllerに繋がらないようです。

Comment: 現在どのような方法で遷移させているのか具体的なコードを提示すれば回答が付きやすいかもしれません。
StoryboardからinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifierでインスタンスを取得していますか？

Comment: 部品のサイズが 0 になっていたり、Y位置が -10000 になっていたりするのかもしれないので、部品の置き方を少し変えてみるという試行もいいかもしれませんね。 （autolayout があれば切ってみる）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let mySecondViewController: UIViewController = SecondViewController()`でUIViewControllerを初期化した場合、Storyboardで設定した内容（Viewの配置とか背景色の変更とか）はmySecondViewControllerに反映されません。

mySecondViewControllerの初期化を以下のようにするとうまくいくと思います。

```
let mySecondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboardのファイル名", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController
```

[補足]
コメントにも書きましたが、mySecondViewControllerがinitial View Controllerではない場合は、以下のようになります。

```
let mySecondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboardのファイル名", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Storyboard ID") as UIViewController
```

Comment: 【再補足】

回答でご指摘されたように、以下のコードを打ちましたが、
(Storyboardの名前は"Main")

これでは遷移先であるSecondViewController.swiftとstoryboard内で「next」と名付けたViewControllerに繋がらないようです。

Comment: 上記の方法は、MainStoryboard内で、SecondViewControllerをinitial View Controllerに設定している場合です。

MainStoryboard内でStoryboard IDをnextとしているなら、以下のコードで大丈夫なはずです。

`let mySecondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("next") as UIViewController`

Comment: user2053939様、ご丁寧な回答有り難うございます。お陰で無事、解決する事ができました！分かりやすい回答、本当に有り難うございます！

Comment: とんでもないです。お役に立てて、何よりです！